# Late 70's early 80's SF Book Club fantasy selection

Tags: story-identification

SF book club selection late 70's - early 80's. Story about a legendry battle/war told from 3 POV: historian/ archaeologist, legend, and what actually happened. May be a religious perspective as well. So good I loaned it out and never saw it again.

Comment: Why didn't you contact the person you loaned it to?

Comment: Here is a listing of a SFBC books from 1953-1982. (When it was in operation) http://www.gostak.org.uk/sfbc/sfbc1.htm  However, this might be a UK SFBC. From a few quick Google searches there appears to have been several SFBCs. In any case, you can look at this list for the years your talking about and see if anything looks familure.

Comment: I was a SFBC member then, but it doesn't sound like a book I would have ordered. But, tell us more!